# Were biological weapons used in WW1?

Tags: weapons, world-war-one

WW1 was, among other things, the first war [where chemical weapons were used on massive scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_weapons_in_World_War_I).

However, I never heard of any mention of biological weapons used in WW1, despite the fact that they were used in warfare for centuries in one form or another.

Is it because there was simply no such use, or because they were used but just weren't effective enough to merit mention/infamy?

Comment: There was a really bad ["Spanish" Flu](http://twitpic.com/cffxir) pandemic that killed perhaps 100 *million* worldwide right in the middle of WWI. For a while it was killing more soldiers than enemy fire was. I've never heard of one side trying to deliberately spread it on purpose, but it wouldn't shock me if some individuals tried that.

Comment: what is your definition of "biological weapons"?

Comment: @LouisRhys - i'm fine with Wiki definition: "Biological warfare (BW) — also known as germ warfare — is the use of biological toxins or infectious agents such as bacteria, viruses, and fungi with intent to kill or incapacitate humans, animals or plants as an act of war. Biological weapons (often termed "bio-weapons", "biological threat agents", or "bio-agents") are living organisms or replicating entities (viruses) that reproduce or replicate within their host victims. Entomological (insect) warfare is also considered a type of Biological Weapon."

Comment: @DVK that's a rather narrow definition. As far back as the Romans (and no doubt earlier) rotting carcasses were catapulted into besieged towns and cities in the hope of poisoning food and water supplies.

Comment: @jwenting - I fail to see how that doesn't fit into Wiki definition.

Comment: Be careful that in search of perfect clarity all meaning is not lost! Arguably someone who deliberately, in time of waw, sneezes without using a handkerchief knowing that the enemy is downwind is technically guilty of biological warfare. But what value is that other than the amusement of nitpicking over a beer? The *interesting* question is whether there was any real (or attempted) deliberate effort on the part of combatants to influence the course of the War using infectious agents.  Anything less is playing with words, not understanding history.

Comment: One clear example is Germany attempting to infect horses in neutral countries (Romania before 1916, US before 1917) with anthrax and glanders to prevent them from being shipped to the allies. Key persons involved here were [Rudolf Nadolny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf_Nadolny) and [Anton Dilger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Dilger). Se also [here](https://www.archives.gov/publications/prologue/2017/fall/tonys-lab) and [here](https://www.npr.org/2017/04/06/522594344/the-unsung-equestrian-heroes-of-world-war-i-and-the-plot-to-poison-them).

Answer (score 8):

To quote my grandfather's memoirs:

> The enemy had gained possession of the high ground in the area during the November battle and even such small bumps as Hill 60 were in their hands.  Entrenched on the forward slopes, they could observe and frequently enfilade the British lines, **and, even more uncomfortably, could drain their positions into our lines**.  The never-ending task of trench drainage became a major scourge to the R.E. and it is difficult for the inexperienced to imagine the tedium of the sappers’ unromantic and apparently losing struggle against the persistent water which eroded the defence and even gnawed away at the soldier’s morale.

Whether you would consider this **biological warfare** or not is debatable.

It is unclear from his memoirs what period of the war this referred to but the immediately following paragraph refers to the death of an `Sgt. V. Caudle NCO i/c Section 3` who is recorded as dying `12/02/1915`.

My grandfather served in the Royal Engineers in WW1 (and WW2 for that matter). At the above date he was serving with the [28th division](http://www.1914-1918.net/28div.htm).

Comment: would be biological warfare, draining sewage into enemy trenches. But was probably unintentional, intended instead to be just harassment, rather than a deliberate campaign of poisoning.

Comment: They are trying to cause trench foot. I think this is biological warfare. All sides would have known very quickly that standing water in the trenches caused the disease. This is why the engineers are trying to pump the water out.

Comment: I would not consider that biological warfare. Water flows downhill. Has been, as long as we can remember. That is a fact of life, not some devious plan hatched in WWI. I doubt that the Royal Engineers drained their trenches uphill, but I would not accuse them of biological warfare.

Comment: If this was biological warfare, you've succeeded in trivializing it by using what should be a very serious offense to label the random crap that happens in the horror-filled chaos of warfare.

Answer (score 5):

I read [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1326439/) that *"The German army was the first to use weapons of mass destruction, both biological and chemical, during the First World War, although their attacks with biological weapons were on a rather small scale and were not particularly successful: covert operations using both anthrax and glanders"*.

And there is a dedicated Wikipedia article for Biological Warfare that also mentions the period of World War 1 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_biological_warfare#First_World_War).

Comment: It would be helpful to add more information from the Wikipedia article linked into the body of this answer, rephrasing or quoting the relevant parts.